# PCA for high dimensional data using Python and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pca, dimension

I have to implement a function for PCA for high dimensional data in Python and I'm stuck at some point. I expect the function to return the same principal components as my function for low dimensional data. I searched already for a solution and found some hints, but something is missing.

I hope someone can help me.

```
these are the steps to create the principal components for the standard PCA routine:

X_normalized

array([[-0.41873524,  0.16431545, -0.56998025, -0.11733312],
       [-0.28466524,  0.30149955,  0.68094323, -0.35746243],
       [ 0.74718755, -1.46799525, -1.38690518,  0.29022802],
       [ 0.51785433,  0.2600977 ,  2.48749719,  0.79531581],
       [-0.56164139,  0.74208255, -1.211555  , -0.61074828]])

# N: number of observations, D: dimensions
N, D = X_normalized.shape

# create covariance matrix
S = np.dot(X_normalized.T, X_normalized) / N

# eigenvalues, eigenvectors
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(S)

# next, I can use the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to create the select the principle components
```

For the PCA for high dimensional data I use the following code:

```
# create 
S = np.dot(X_normalized, X_normalized.T) / N

# eigenvalues, eigenvectors
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(S)
```

As expected, the eigenvalues are the very same as returned by the standard PCA routine. The eigenvectors is a N x N matrix.

I understood, I have to multiply the eigenvectors of X * X.T with X.T to the the eigenvectors for the regular covariance matrix but

```
np.dot(X_normalized.T, eig_vecs)
```

returns something different. What am I missing here?

Kind regards,
Stephan

I'm epxecting to get the very same eigenvectors from the PCA routine for high dimensional data, as for the regular PCA function.

Answer (score 0):

... finally if found the solution for my problem. I just had to normalize the eigenvectors (columns).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).